# Trying to write a alarm clock in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program to remind a user to take breaks. Here is the code:

```
import datetime
import os
from playsound import playsound
import time

# current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
# print(current_time)
running = True
while running:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    new_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    # print(current_time)
    breaktime = datetime.timedelta(
                        days=0,
                        hours=0,
                        minutes=1
    )
    times = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)
    time.sleep(6)
    new = current_time + times
    if new_time == new:
        print("hello")
        playsound('Take_Flight.mp3')
        running = False

    break
```

The program does not play the sound `Take_Flight.mp3` and it does not print `hello`.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Let us ask: What doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't ring

Comment: like it doesnt get to the print('hello') part

Comment: I guess that has to do with the fact that you're comparing `if .now() == current_time + 5 seconds` (pesudo code to make it easier to understand what `if new_time == new` does. So ask yourself, can `now` in time be equal to `now + 5sec`? Can those ever be true/equal? It's like asking Python to compare year `1995 == 2035`, won't ever be true because it's two different years, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your alarm does not ring is because of the `break` statement at the bottom line of your code. The `while` loop simply ends without looping over and over again as you intended. I believe if you remove that your code will work. As an alternative to what you wrote you can also make the program wait for 5 min and then ring without getting the current time:

```
while True
    time.sleep(300000) 
    print("hello")
    playsound('Take_Flight.mp3')
```